# How do you establish an order of events, or steps, in a snaplogic pipeline

Tags: snaplogic

I'd like to establish an order of events in my snaplogic pipeline. I'd like to perform (for example) a SQL Execute snap, and then after that, another different snap. There's no input/output data relationship between these snaps. I just want one to proceed first, and then after that, the next one. Is there a snap, or some other feature of the tool, that allows you to establish an arbitrary order of snaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to connect the snaps in sequence if you want to establish an order of events in your SnapLogic pipeline.

For most implementations, (say) if you want to execute Snap B after Snap A, put a **Tail** snap between them (connecting Snap A and Snap B). This will ensure that Snap B is executed after Snap A.

Comment: Thanks, this is the way my team is doing it. You usually have to manually add a View to the end and beginning of the two snaps, to put the Tail snap in between them.

Comment: Yep, that's the pattern to follow

Answer (score 0):

In such a situation, I create one pipeline by task, and orchestrate the tasks with a chain of `Execute Pipeline` snaps.

This provides several advantages:

- separation of the topic of each task from the orchestration need
- makes development and testing of each task easy, with possibility of running each of them independently
- each sub-pipeline may have 0 input and 0 output, this is not an issue for the `Execute Pipeline` snap, that will still be able to be chained with only metadata at its output.